# There are no form controls registered with this group yet. If you're using ngModel,you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting the above error while trying to test in spec file for a form model submit

```
it('should require valid form'), ()=> {
 const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExtensionComponent);
 const component = fixture.componentInstance;
 let date = New Date();
 expect(component.loading).toEqual(false);
 component.extensionForm.setValue({
  listingPrice: 100
  payoffDate: new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()))
 });
 expect(component.extensionForm.valid).toEqual(false);
```

});

Comment: you should provide us the code of the ExtensionComponent. Otherwise it will be impossible to help you with that

Comment: Please add the error details in the question instead of saying above error which will be confused what error exactly you mean,